# Find volume of region bound by $y=x^2$, $y=4-x^2$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Find volume of region bound by $y=x^2$, $y=4-x^2$

I graphed this and it's a graph of two parabolas

A) About the $x$-axis. I'm not sure if I use a washer method using

$$V=\int{\pi(4-x^2)^2}dx - \int{\pi (x^2)^2}dx $$

with $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{2}$

this comes out to be $\displaystyle{\frac{64π√2}{15}}$

B) About $y=4$

Comment: The question should appear within the body of the question, not only in the title. (This was the main reason for my edit).

Answer (score 1):

For the rotation about the $x$-axis, the setup is basically right. However, $x$ travels from $-\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{2}$.

So either integrate over the interval $[-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ or else exploit the symmetry, integrate from $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$ and double the result.

For the second problem, turn the  sheet of paper upside down, and you will see that you know the answer. But if you want to use formulas, the outer radius is $4-x^2$ and the inner radius is $4-(4-x^2)$.

**Remark:** You probably calculated both integrals of the OP. It will save some time, and cut down on the probability of error, if  we note that the volume is
$$2\int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \pi(16-8x^2)\,dx.$$
The calulation should be easy, particularly if we rewrite as $16\pi\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}(2-x^2)\,dx$.